# Double click happening when opening modal

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, modal-dialog, openlayers

**Problem description**

I don't really know if what is happening is indeed a double click event, I'm having a really hard time debugging this problem.

I have a map component (OpenLayers) inside a page called 'map', in this page I can create and edit some geometries. When I toggle a 'edit' tool on and select one of these geometries a modal opens with some properties of this geometry which I can edit and save. One of this properties is the color, which is selected with [`ion-select`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select). When I click in the input of `ion-select` a kind of popover pops up for the color selection.

My problem is that, when the geometry of the map is aligned in the same position that the `ion-select` input, this popover opens automatically, like it was clicked. None of the others inputs are affected in the same way, which would be the selection or activation of these inputs.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked">Estilo: </ion-label>
    <ion-select okText="Ok" cancelText="Cancelar" placeholder="Selecione uma" [(ngModel)]="modalColor" value="{{modalColor}}" [disabled]="modalGps">
        <ion-select-option value="yellow">Amarelo</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="red">Vermelho</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="pink">Rosa</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="purple">Roxo</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="blue">Azul</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="gray">Cinza</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="white">Branco</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="black">Preto</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

```js
this.map.on('click', (evt) => {
    let feature = this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
        evt.pixel,  (feature) => {
            if (feature.getId() !== 'accTrackingPoint' && feature.getId() !== 'trackingPoint') { 
                return feature; 
            }
        }, 
        {hitTolerance: this.hit_tolerance}
    );

    if (feature && feature.getGeometry().getType() === "Point") {
        return this.editPoint(feature);
    }
});

editPoint(feature: Feature): Promise<void> {
    // Get data from current point feature
    ... 

    // Open edit modal
    return this.openPointModal(this.projectId, id, coord, name, obs, color, isGps);
}

async openPointModal (projectId, id, coord, name, obs, color, gps=false) {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
        component: ModalPointPage,
        componentProps: { modalProjectID: projectId, modalID: id, modalCoord: coord, modalName: name, modalObs: obs, modalColor: color, modalGps: gps },
        backdropDismiss: false
    });

    //Get the data returned from the Modal and add to global variable
    modal.onDidDismiss().then((modalData) => {
        this.handleClosePointModal(modalData);
    });
    
    return await modal.present();       
}
```

**Images to illustrate the problem**

[image: Point aligned with text input and not triggering it when clicked]

*Point aligned with text input and not triggering it when clicked*

---

[image: Point aligned with select input and triggering the popover when clicked]

*Point aligned with select input and triggering the popover when clicked*

---

**Some system information**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.10.1 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.2
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
```

- OpenLayers v5.3

---

I applied some logs in several related events to see if there was something firing more than once, but everything is firing just one time. I create a click event on the select input using angular [`(click)`](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#binding-to-user-input-events) and it is also fired when the popover is opened, I believe that this may contribute to the idea that a double click is happening, although previous logs do not point this out. I also added the [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) method to the `map.on('click')` event, as suggested in comments, but there was no change in behavior.

---

It's important to point out that this problem don't happen for the browser version, only in the app version.

Comment: have you tried stopping the event propagation. evt.stopPropagation?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried to do that now but the problem keeps happening.